# Stackoverflow exception while testing Miller Rabin

Tags: java, exception, primes

All,

I have implemented a code that generates 2 random prime numbers and the multiplication of these 2 numbers should pass the Miller Rabin primality test. However, my code keeps looping all the time trying to find a number that passes Miller rabin test and ends up with a Stackoverflow exception. Here is the code:

```
private void populateRandomPrimes()
{
    onePrimeValue = RandomPrime.getValue();

    do
    {
        secondPrimeValue= RandomPrime.getValue();
    }while(onePrimeValue == secondPrimeValue);

    BigInteger calcNum = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(onePrimeValue*secondPrimeValue));

    try
    {
        **if (calcNum.isProbablePrime(20))**
            populateMultiplicativeForPlayer();
        else
            populateRandomPrimes();
    }
    catch (Exception io)
    {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the code above:
1 > RandomPrime class returns a random **prime** number
2 > Both onePrimeValue and secondPrimeValue should be **different**
3 > Since the code line : `if (calcNum.isProbablePrime(20))` never returns a `true`, I end up calling the same till I get `Stackoverflow` exception

Can anyone suggest me how to get around with this issue?

Comment: Maybe try not use recursion...  Rather put it into a large while loop. You can even place a counter and get it to stop/fail after a certain amount of iterations.

Comment: If you are sure that `calcNum.isProbablePrime()` works correctly, you should as Paul suggested.

Comment: Well isProbablePrime() does work fine, But I never get a prime number from 2 primes .. I am only getting composite primes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my comment below your question...

```
private void populateRandomPrimes()
{
    while (true){
      onePrimeValue = RandomPrime.getValue();

      do
      {
          secondPrimeValue= RandomPrime.getValue();
      }while(onePrimeValue == secondPrimeValue);

      BigInteger calcNum = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(onePrimeValue*secondPrimeValue));

      try
      {
          if (calcNum.isProbablePrime(20)){
              populateMultiplicativeForPlayer();
              return;
          }
      }
      catch (Exception io)
      {
          io.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the calcNum computation inside of the do-while loop and add an extra condition:

```
private void populateRandomPrimes()
{
    onePrimeValue = RandomPrime.getValue();
    BigInteger calcNum = null;
    do {
        secondPrimeValue= RandomPrime.getValue();
        calcNum = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(onePrimeValue*secondPrimeValue));
    } while(onePrimeValue.equals(secondPrimeValue) && !(calcNum.isProbablePrime(20));

    //if you get here, calcNum isProbPrime, so no need to check again
    try {
        populateMultiplicativeForPlayer();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You are running into this problem because you don't have a definitive base case for your recursion.  Also, don't use `==` on objects unless you know what you're doing.  Your do-while condition should have used `.equals()` to compare `onePrimeValue` and `secondPimeValue`

The worst case scenario with this approach is that your program will get stuck in an [infinite loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop) because the exit condition of the do-while loop is never satisfied.  To remedy this, you can add a third condition to the loop to ensure that it terminates after a fixed number of iterations.

Comment: well `secondPrimeValue` and `onePrimeValue` are of type `int`. So I don't need to use `.equals()` . And I am infact only running into the worse scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private BigInteger generateAppropriateNumber() {
    BigInteger result;
    boolean isOk = false;
    while (isOk == false) {
        onePrimeValue = RandomPrime.getValue();
        do {
            secondPrimeValue= RandomPrime.getValue();
        } while(onePrimeValue.equals(secondPrimeValue));
        BigInteger result = 
              new BigInteger(Integer.toString(onePrimeValue * secondPrimeValue));
        if (result.isProbablePrime(20)) {
            isOk = true;
        }            
    }
    return result;
}

private void populateRandomPrimes() {
    populateMultiplicativeForPlayer(generateAppropriateNumber());
}
```

I.e.

1. Use loop instead of recursion to avoid stack increase.
2. Don't use global variables. It is really bad style.